# Limits and Continuity- Sandwich Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}   \sinh x \tanh \left(\frac1x\right)$$

I am sure that the *Sandwich theorem* applies here but how do I go about it? Do I separate the terms or just put in one range of values for both?

Answer (score 2):

OK, as $x \to 0 \ \sinh x \to 0$ and $-1 \leq \tanh \frac{1}{x} \leq 1$ hence the limit is 0.

Comment: Yeah. But the question specified to "use Sandwich theorem as one of the methods".

Comment: OK I'm sorry, pls see the edit. Do you need additional explanation?

Comment: All good now thanks.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this to apply sandwich theorem:

$$0<\sinh x\tanh\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac{2e-2e^{-1}}{2e^{1/x}+2e^{-1/x}}<\frac1{e^{1/|x|}}\to 0$$